# SOAP::Lite module installation on cPanel

Tags: perl, cpanel, soaplite

I am creating a custom module to be placed in the directory /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel.  My perl module requires SOAP::Lite.  Since the scripts placed in the directory /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel are run under cpanel's internal perl version 5.6.2, does on install the SOAP::Lite module?

Trying to build the module with cpanel's build tool fails as another perl module is require to build the source module for soap::lite from cpan.

Answer (score 0):

Perl modules are usually installed using the [cpan program that comes with Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/cpan.html).  This checks all the dependencies for you and installs everything you need.  This is what you should do.

If you don't have the ability to access and run this program, then you may not have permission to install modules at all.  Possibly you could get whoever is running your system to do it for you (also ask them to upgrade your nearly 9 year old version of Perl while they are at it!).

Beyond that, there are not many options.  You could try building the required modules on another, similar system and copying over--if you enjoy pain.

Comment: Well, I looked into CPanel a little more and found this, which should help you: http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/SoftwareDevelopmentKit/InstallingInternalPerlModules